# Как задать два знака после запятой?

Tags: python, форматирование, prettytable

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable()

box = list(range(1, 6))
wine_wort = [i*.85 for i in box]
sugarl = [i*.142 for i in box]
sugarkg = [i/.62 for i in sugarl]
juice = [i*.86 for i in wine_wort]
fruite = [i/.6 for i in juice]

columns = {
    'Емкость,л': box,
    'Сусло,л': wine_wort,
    'В т.ч.сахара': sugarl,
    'Нужно сахара': sugarkg,
    'В т.ч. сока': juice,
    'Нужно фруктов': fruite,
}

for key, item in columns.items():
    table.add_column(key, item)

print(table)
```

Результат: в каждой графе, где указано количество, немеренное количество знаков после запятой. Как оставить только два?

Comment: `print(round(123.456789999999, 2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

округлите числа с помощью функции `round`

к примеру вместо

```
wine_wort = [i * .85 for i in box]
```

пишите

```
wine_wort = [round(i * .85, 2) for i in box]
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать [стили](https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable#style-options), конкретно `float_format`.

***Пример (UPD):***

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable()

box = list(range(1, 6))
wine_wort = [i*.85 for i in box]
sugarl = [i*.142 for i in box]
sugarkg = [i/.62 for i in sugarl]
juice = [i*.86 for i in wine_wort]
fruite = [i/.6 for i in juice]

columns = {
    'Емкость,л': box,
    'Сусло,л': wine_wort,
    'В т.ч.сахара': sugarl,
    'Нужно сахара': sugarkg,
    'В т.ч. сока': juice,
    'Нужно фруктов': fruite,
}

for key, item in columns.items():
    table.add_column(key, item)
    table.float_format[key] = '.2'  # <------

print(table)
```

Comment: я юзер, поконкретнее и на данной программе можно?

Comment: @сергей Привёл полный текст программы.